# how to display the roles in a resulted dropdown from the particular office selected?

Tags: c#, angular

i would like to display the roles in a dropdown from the offices which i have selected from a office dropdown.
but here is a problem here, the office selected dropdown is on page , but the dropdown which the roles should display is inside the ISSUEPOPUP BOX .

As of now we have implementation like all the roles are displaying ,we need to rearrrange that roles on basis of the office selected

i have angular code as

```
    officeSelected() {
        var selectedRegions = '';
        var selectedOfficeId = '';
        if (this.scope.selected.offices != undefined) {
            selectedRegions = Array.prototype.map.call(this.scope.selected.offices, function (item) { return item.val; }).join(",");
            selectedOfficeId = Array.prototype.map.call(this.scope.selected.offices, function (item) { return item.val; }).join(",");
            this.setSupervisor(selectedRegions, 'office');
            this.setTechnicians(selectedRegions, 'office');

            this.scope.selected.regions = null;
            this.scope.selected.subregions = null;
            this.scope.selected.gbobranches = null;
            this.scope.selected.supervisors = null;
            this.scope.selected.technicians = null;
        }
```

& in TS file , when we select a popupbox

```
 getRoles() {
        if (this.scope.selected != undefined && this.scope.selected.roles != undefined) {
            this.scope.selected.roles = null;
        }
        //if (this.officeIds) {
        //    if (this.officeType) {

        //    }
        //}
        this.userService.getOfficeOrganizationalRoles(this.officeIds)
            .then((response) => {
                this.scope.roles = response.data;
            });
    }
```

please help me how to implement this  feature

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're filtering `offices` on some page and display a list of `rules` in a popup dialog? And that second list requires the `officeIds` but doesn't have them? If so, you'll want to use a service to share the selected data.

Comment: yes thats correct ,but the second list contains roles (eg: a,b,c)in a dropdown .now i need to dispay those a,b,c  as per the selected office ID

Comment: for example ,if a,b,c are the roles & x,y,z   are the OfficeID  (a=x,b=y,c=z) ,as of now i am displaying all the a,b,c in dropdown ,but now if 'a ' is selected it should display only X in the dropdown.